# Any video player that can show two subtitles at a time?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, subtitle

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 .

Is there any video player that can show two subtitles at a time while watching?

Thank you.

Comment: what type of two subtitle's? can you please explain?

Comment: @Tarun If I had the screen shot I will be familiar , why would I post here then ?

Comment: two subtitles in different languages in the same time have to appear while watching the video. @Tarun .

Comment: ya edited my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a tool called [2srt2ass](http://pas-bien.net/2srt2ass/) that can take two langauages in two separate subtitle SRT files and combines them into one SSA/ASS file, showing one language at the top of the screen and one at the bottom.

Something like that's probably the cleanest solution in terms of playback (you can just use the player you would have anyway) but it's a bit of a faff to get started if you've got lots of videos to do this for.

Alternatives that do the same thing: [SrtMerger](http://www.srtmerger.org/en/)

There's also [an `awk` script on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606978&page=2&p=11911410#post11911410) that might be able to do the same thing.

Comment: But there is no way to integrate with a player ?

Comment: Not in any meaningful way, no. At the least you're in a position where you have to fish out the subtitles, send them somewhere for merging, put them in the right place and then select that subtitle.

Answer (score 4):

Smplayer is GUI for the famous *mplayer*, the engine behind many players. It's now easy with stock Smplayer to display two subtitles. Just select your 2nd subtitle as a *Secondary track* and the player should automatically position it on the top.
According to the [blog](http://blog.smplayer.info/displaying-two-subtitles-at-the-same-time-now-its-possible/):

> This is available since SVN r6474 and requires mpv.

To install mpv: `sudo apt-get install mpv`

If it still doesn't work, try resetting the configuration file. According to Smplayer [FAQ](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/faq.php):

> The easiest way to find the configuration files of SMPlayer is by selecting the option "Open configuration folder" in the Help menu. If you want to delete the current configuration and start with the default settings, just delete the file smplayer.ini (important: be sure SMPlayer is not running when you delete the file).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [DualSub](http://dualsub.sourceforge.net/) to merge subtitles. DualSub combines two SRT subtitles splitting the available width of the screen in two columns. It is highly configurable, and the resulting merged SRT can be used in different players (e.g. VLC, Windows Media Player, etc, even in your TV).

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm
Extended options appeared to be useful (like subtitles synchronisation and extended show delay)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (bash) script, save it as mergeSubtitle.sh run it by typing "bash mergeSubtitle.sh" in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/sh
# mergeSubtitle.sh: Script to merge 2 SRT subtitle into single one
# This is script is freely available under the GNU/GPL license
# Author: Antonymous X
# antonymousx@gmail.com
# 07/19/2015

test "$#" -ne 3  && echo -e "Usage: 2subs \"<LANGUAGE_FILE_1>\" \"<LANGUAGE_FILE_2>\" \"<COMBINED_LANGUAGE_FILE_OUTPUT>\"\nDouble quotes are required in most cases unless the filenames do not contain whitespaces"
test "$#" -ne 3 && exit 1 
lang_file1=$1
lang_file2=$2
lang_file3=$3
# Create an empty output file since we'll be appending
touch "$lang_file3"
cp /dev/null "$lang_file3"
# Load srt files into memory and set IFS to '#' to avoid confusion with whitespaces
file1=$(cat "$lang_file1"|sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(,[[:digit:]]{3,3}\n|([[:digit:]]){1,4})\n|([[:alpha:]])\n/\1|/g'|sed -r 's/\|$/#/g')
file2=$(cat "$lang_file2"|sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(,[[:digit:]]{3,3}\n|([[:digit:]]){1,4})\n/\1|/g'|sed -r 's/(.$)/\1\n/g')
IFS='#'
# Split the content.  Notice double quoting so it prints newlines
for line in `echo "$file1"`
do
     LINE=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $1}'|sed  ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'|sed -r 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g'|sed -r 's/[[:space:]]//g')
     TIME=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $2}'|sed  ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'|sed -r 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g'|sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]+//g')
     DIALOG=$(echo $line|cut -d'|' -f3-|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'|sed -r 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g'|sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]+//g'|sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]+//g'|sed -r 's/\|/ /g')
     DIALOG2=`echo "$file2"|grep "^$LINE|"|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n|\t/ /g'|sed -r 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g'|awk -F'|' '{print $3}'|sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]+//g'`
# Display a basic progress bar
     echo -n "#"   
# Write to output file
     echo -e "$LINE\n$TIME\nl1:$DIALOG\nl2:$DIALOG2\n" >> "$lang_file3"
done
echo #
# Write a funny message
echo Thou have been served
exit 0
```